# Transistors - What is re model?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, bjt

I would like to know an in depth definition of the re transistor model in BJTs. I know most diagrams very well, but the definition does not. Also, can you guys help me differentiate the small scale transistor model into the re transistor model? I am using Robert Boylestad's Electronic Devices and Circuit Theory by the way.

Comment: It has to do with a resistor on the emitter of a BJT, such that it creates negative feedback, useful for many things. We are not a classroom per se, so show us what you understand so far.

Comment: What happens to the emitter current, when 100 microVolts AC Peak Peak is fed to the base, atop 0.6 volts of DC base bias that sets the emitter current to 1mA? What will 100uV AC PP cause?

Answer (score 1):

The so-called "re-model" is a BJT model which is - according to my opinion - not very close to te physical reality and, hence, not very useful. In contrast, I think it is even confusing because some people (even authors) call this element "inherent emitter resistor" which is simply wrong.

It is not a resistive element and it does not belong to the emitter.

Instead, it is simply the inverse of the transconductance gm (re=1/gm), which connects the controlling input voltage Vbe with the controlled quantity (collector current Ic): 
**gm=d(Ic)/d(Vbe)**.

(For my opinion, to understand the real transistor function it does not help at all to use the inverse transconductance re=1/gm within the model and to treat it as a resistive element).

Comment: The comment above from Sparky256 is a very good example for the confusing use of this symbol. An external emitter resistor Re (causing negative feedback) is an ohmic linear resistor (large letter) whereas a symbol with small letters (re) always indicates a dynamic (differential) resistor.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather vague, but I'll guess you are asking what h<sub>RE</sub> is.  RE stands for *reverse emitter*.  This is the primary characteristic when looking backward at a transistor in common emitter configuration.

In the common emitter configuration, the base is the input and the collector is the output.  The more common h<sub>FE</sub> describes the main forward characteristic (FE = forward emitter), which is the gain from base to collector.  This is a dimensionless quantity since both values have units of current.

The primary characteristic when looking at this circuit in reverse, is how much a small change in the output voltage causes the output (the collector current) to change.  For a perfect BJT, the collector current is strictly a function of the base current and the gain, and doesn't vary with collector voltage.  Of course real transistors do have some dependence on voltage.  Since the h<sub>RE</sub> value is ΔV/ΔI, it has units of resistance.  This can be thought of as the apparent resistance of the current source that the collector is ideally.  Note that this value is infinite for a ideal current source.

Most transistor datasheets have a graph showing the collector current as a function of collector voltage, with several curves of different base currents.  After you get past a volt or so, note how the collector current flattens out as more collector voltage is applied.  If it were perfectly flat, then the collector current wouldn't be a function of voltage at all.  However, the current still rises a little as more voltage is applied.  It is this incremental applied voltage divided by the resulting incremental current that h<sub>RE</sub> tries to describe.  To really nail down h<sub>RE</sub>, the operating point from which the incremental changes were made need to be specified.

Comment: Olin Lathrop - I am afraid you misunderstood the question. The question was about the "re model" - that means: Explanation of one of the available small-signal the BJT models (in this case the so called "re-model")  .