# What is the best transistor model for bjt transistor ac analysis(middle response)?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, ac, bjt

Nowadays I am working on bjt transistor ac analysis. I use r(e) model for bjt transistors ac analysis in my university. I know there are separate methods for low frequency medium frequency high frequency in Bjt Transistors.
I have read in some comments that the re model does not correspond to real physical values.
[Transistors - What is re model?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/398644/transistors-what-is-re-model)
see LvW 's comment.
What is the most realistic model I should use if I want to work on ac analysis of medium frequency bjt transistors (amplifier design etc.)?

Comment: hm, we're talking about simulation of BJTs, right? because I'd simply trust the semiconductor model that your simulator has –  these things don't care much about human interpretation of what low and high frequencies are...

Comment: I meant taking the paper and pencil and analyzing it. :)

Comment: Can you show us how r'e model looks like?  Do you mean T-model? https://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/412/handouts/5.6%20Small%20Signal%20Operation%20and%20Models/section%205_6%20%20Small%20Signal%20Operation%20and%20Models%20lecture.pdf (page 55?) The Hybrid-Π and the T circuit models are equivalent they both will result in the same correct answer!

Comment: @G36 https://pasteboard.co/J2a0C1k.jpg

Comment: @G36 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2c5ETb2Hz6aUWVqb3U1Q083NjQ/view   please see PAGE   265

Comment: OK, I see. So where is the problem?

Comment: https://ibb.co/0FvzbCj   do you think this model is useful? mean r(e) model

Comment: @G36 that handout you linked is surprisingly good. It also contains the answer to the OP question at page 57: "The Hybrid-Π and the T circuit models are equivalent—they both will result in the same correct answer!". The OP is confused because LvW has a dogmatic view "voltage cause current" that makes him think that there is only one true and sacred way to model a transistor.

Comment: Yes this model is useful, I use it here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/489944/mid-band-magnitude-gain-of-a-cascode-amplifier/490116#490116  @LvW  had in mind that this model does not show how a BJT's work in a physical way. The BJT in the active region behaves just like a voltage-controlled current source. The collector acts like a current source whose current is determined by the base-emitter voltage ( transconductance device) https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/302832/about-bjt-jfet-mosfet-transconductance/302848#302848

Comment: But the re-model does not show it but it will give you the correct answer.

Comment: @SredniVashtar Yes, indeed this handout is very good. I hope that the OP will read it whole because it's worth it.

Comment: @G36 thanks for your answer .This helped me a lot.